# yii2 есть проблема, при создании пользователя

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Я создаю пользователя с помощью модели User, и выполняю user->save(). Пользователь создаётся, но мне необходимо в другую таблицу сразу же при регистрации пользователя создавать запись с id этого пользователя. Как это сделать? что-то типо $user->getId()?
Т.е. мне надо что бы было так:

```
$user->save();
$id = $user->getId(); // Тут должен быть id только что созданного пользователя.
```

Помогите кто сможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да. $id = $user->id; вполне правильный код. не забывайте и про событие afterSave(). там удобно писать логику для постоянных манипуляций. объект (модель) $user там доступен через $this